# simple profile page for a job site

Tags: php, mysql

I've done a login and registration for my site and it works fine.

Now I just want to make a simple profile page where the user can see all their details.

I'm only able to get back the username, so I'm unsure how to get the rest of their details.

Here is the code for registering and logging in:

```
function selectUser($conn, $username, $password)
{
    $query = "SELECT password FROM login WHERE username = :username"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

    $stmt->execute();

    if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        if (md5($password) == $row->password)
        {  
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            //$_SESSION['password'] = $password; DO NOT DO THIS
            echo "Welcome, you are now logged in as " . $username; 
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    } else  {
        //echo "Your details were not found";
        return false;
    }
}

function selectNew($conn, $name, $username, $password, $contact, $occupation, $role, $picture)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO login VALUES (NULL, :name, :username, :password, :contactNumber, :occupation, :role, :pic)";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $stmt->bindValue(':contactNumber', $contact);
    $stmt->bindValue(':occupation', $occupation);
    $stmt->bindValue(':role', $role);
    $stmt->bindValue(':pic', $picture);
    $affected_rows = $stmt->execute();

    if ($affected_rows == 1)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Don't worry, the password has been hashed.

heres what I've tried:

```
function selectUser($conn, $username, $password)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = :username"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    echo $row['occupation'];
    echo $row['role'];
}
```

2nd attempt:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
    echo "Welcome, you are now logged in as <b>".$_SESSION['username']."</b> <img class='clientView' src='images/loginIcon.png' alt='client'>"; }
    else { 
    echo "You are currently not logged in";
}

$user   = $_SESSION["username"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = :username"; 

$term = $conn->prepare($query);
$term->bindValue(':username', $user);
$term->execute();

if ($username = $term->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    echo "<li><h3>" . $user->username ." ". $user->user_ID . "</h3></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to replace your query in `selectUser(...)` with `SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = :username`. Note the `*` after the `SELECT` command, which functions as a wild card and thus asks for every single column of each row it finds (instead of just the `password` column as you are currently asking for.

You could then, as you iterate over the returned rows, access other columns of the user via your `$row` variable. Just like you access the user's hashed password with `$row->password`, you could access `$row->contactNumber`.

**A note about good practice:**

Depending on the case, I would not recommend doing a wildcard (`*`) `SELECT` command at login. In fact, I would recommend simply hashing the password prior to the query and attempting to then qualify your query with `WHERE username = :username AND password = :password` (obviously, bind the hashed password to `:password`). Instead of asking for the password column, or wildcard columns, you could `SELECT` the row's unique ID.

This way, you don't even need to iterate over the returned rows at all...you only have to make sure *any* row returned (see [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)) to see if the user can be successfully "logged in". You can then cache the returned row's unique ID into your session, and then do subsequent queries as necessary for other pieces of information...such as the user's role or contact number. This effectively brings the complexity of all of your query processing down from linear time to constant time...a minor, but still non-trivial, improvement for an application.

Also, as a word of warning, this login system is very simple and easily spoofed. PHP sessions provide some security, but they are not full-proof. A sniffer snagging the session cookie will allow them to log in as the user whom they sniffed it from. I would recommend looking into adding in your own session layer as well once you have the rest of your login system implemented. And absolutely use SSL.

**A note about optimization:**

Using a wildcard (`*`) in a `SELECT` command is actually a prime place for a speed bottleneck to occur. If you know exactly what columns you want from the database, it is best to ask for them explicitly. For example, instead of `*`, you could do `password,occupation,role`.

Comment: you lost me at the "You could then, as you iterate over the returned rows, access other columns of the user via your $row variable. Just like you access the user's hashed password with $row->password, you could access $row->contactNumber"  could you provide an example or simplify it a bit more . thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
You have user name in session right.
Just pass this value in where condition of mysql .and get the entire record from login table .just show where ever  you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Not dissimilar to your existing code - use the session variable you set when the user logs in

```
$username=!empty( $_SESSION['username'] ) ? $_SESSION['username'] : false;
$sql='select * from `login` where `username`=:username;';

$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
if( $stmt && $username ){
    $stmt->bindValue(':username',$username);
    $result=$stmt->execute();
    if( $result ){
        $rs=$stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
        /* display results from $rs */
        /*
            There should most likely only be one record!!
        */
        $row=$rs[0];

        foreach( $row as $column => $value )echo $column.' '.$value;

    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming the user has logged in successfully and you have set the session variable `username` then select his/her details from the database... which bit do you not understand?

Comment: the bit when your fetching the results, ill put up what ive done

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `SELECT` statement to return the other values you want to store in your `$_SESSION` variables and then access them each with `$row->{variable}`

Just make sure you populate the `$_SESSION` after you do your password check